# How to check each column data in a csv file, before importing into mysql database in php?

Tags: php, mysqli, import-csv

My columns headings are id, name, phone. If i gave name in id column the data is not inserting but message is showing as "successful import". I want to show the message like the "data is not properly defined". How to validate code before importing into mysql?

I tried to check with the if and else conditions but didn't get the actual result which i need.

```
$sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO `all`(`id`, `name`,`phone`)   VALUES ('".$getData[0]."','".$getData[1]."','".$getData[2]."')";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if($result)
 {
echo  "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert(\"CSV File has been successfully Imported.\");                    
  }</script>";
else {
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\"> alert(\"Invalid File Format/ Data Please check file is csv and data as per headings.\");      
}</script>";
}
```

I expect the alert message as "improper data" but getting "successful import".

Answer (score 0):

you can use is_int(), to check wether the value (in your case $getData[0]) is integer or not.

before adding value in query

```
if(!is_int($getData[0])
{ 
    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\"> alert(\"Improper Data.\");      
    }</script>";

}
else
{
    // insert query code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Validation should be done before any INSERT, this way you can do it:

```
<?php

//validation of csv

if (false === validateCsvRow($getData)) {
    echo "data is not properly defined";

    // or better to throw an exception - uncomment to see difference
    // throw new \InvalidArgumentException("data is not properly defined");

    die; //end script execution
}

// if validation is okay script continues.

$sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO `all`(`id`, `name`,`phone`)   VALUES ('".$getData[0]."','".$getData[1]."','".$getData[2]."')";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if($result)
 {
echo  "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert(\"CSV File has been successfully Imported.\");                    
  }</script>";
else {
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\"> alert(\"Invalid File Format/ Data Please check file is csv and data as per headings.\");      
}</script>";
}


function validateCsvRow(array $data) : bool
{
    $result = 1;

    //check if id is not set
    if (!isset($data[0]) {
        $result *= 0;
    }

    //check if id is not integer
    if (!is_int($data[0]) {
        $result *= 0;
    }

    //check if name is not set
    if (!isset($data[1]) {
        $result *= 0;
    }

    //check if name is not string
    if (!is_string($data[1]) {
        $result *= 0;
    }

    $minimumNameLength = 1; //number of characters

    //check if name has at least n characters
    if (!strlen($data[1]) < $minimumNameLength) {
        $result *= 0;
    }

    //return 1 => true if all was ok
    //or 0 => false if at least one check was not ok.
    return (bool) $result;

}
```

the code above uses typing, if you are using an old php version change

```
function validateCsvRow(array $data) : bool
```

to:

```
function validateCsvRow($data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Field order in CSV can vary, eg. column 0 must not always be "id".

Consider this CSV:

```
name, id, phone
'Alice', 1, 1234
'Bob', 2, 5678
```

and this code:

```
$sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO `all`(`id`, `name`,`phone`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$header = null;
while($row = fgetcsv($handle)) {
    if ($header == null) {
        $header = $row;
        continue;
    }
    $data = array_combine($header, $row);
    // $data is now an assoziative array, eg. you can grab "id" by name

    $stmt->execute([ $data['id'], $data['name'], $data['phone'] ]);
}
```